# Deleting browser history from other user

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, history

I've recently got my domain account blocked. Now they have to inspect the entire computer and I do have some stuff in my browser history that I would like them to not see.

I do have access to the local administrator so I can Read/Write to the local files of the domain account, but can not open the browser to delete history the normal way. (tried `runas /domain\user firefox.exe` but does not work)
The browser is **Firefox**. on windows

So my question is "Is there a way to delete a users browser history from an administrator account?" as is there a file that stores history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox browser history is stored inside the profile folder, which is:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\something.default\
```

Two files may be concerned:

- `places.sqlite` - browsing history
- `formhistory.sqlite` - form data history

Save and delete the file(s) you want kept private, returning them after the computer
is fixed.